# How can I make use of pagination with GraphQL library for python gql?

Tags: python, graphql

I have access to a GraphQL server that contains, among other things, links to PDF files. I am trying to query this GraphQL server using the gql python library. I have been able to get the library to work with our own servers successfully, but the server is returning too many records and so the system is timing out (afaik). My understanding is that in order to solve this problem I need to make use of pagination, and while I understand what this is and why I would want to do it, I have zero idea about how to do this in python.

Here is the code I've written so far

```
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
import asyncio
import requests
import os
import urllib.request
from pandas.io import sql
import sqlalchemy as sqla
import hashlib
from gql import gql, Client
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport
from datetime import time, tzinfo, timedelta, datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd


database = 'database'
con    = sqla.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + "/" + database)



def generate_transport(brand):
    transport = AIOHTTPTransport(
    configuration_details[brand]['url'],
    headers={'Authorization': configuration_details[brand]['bearer']})    
    return transport

  
    
async def main(transport, query):

    # Using `async with` on the client will start a connection on the transport
    # and provide a `session` variable to execute queries on this connection
    async with Client(
        transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True,
    ) as session:
        gql_query = gql(query)
        result = await session.execute(gql_query)
        return result


q1 = """query DocumentsAndSoftware {technicalDocumentsEntries (limit: 4000) {... on technicalDocuments_document_Entry { id title technicalDocuments { ... on technicalDocuments_document_BlockType { fallbackFileUrl documentLanguage file { id url dateModified } } }}}}"""
transport = generate_transport('endpoint1')
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
result = loop.create_task(main(transport, q1))

output = result.result()
```

If I set the limit value to be too large (i.e. 4000 is too large, but 3000 works) then I get a time out error, as pasted below.

I don't know how to implement pagination in this case. I assume I need to be able to dynamically adjust the limit value and tell it to keep track of which records have been returned and then adjust the starting point for the next round of retrievals to come immediately after the ones already returned- but I don't know how to do this. I'm also concerned that the order of the results set could potentially change between recurring retrievals, i.e. the first time I run the query, it would return the results in ordering A, so I would retrieve 3000 records from the first query, but when re-running the query to have it pull the next 3000 records it may not be in the same order.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gql/transport/aiohttp.py in execute(self, document, variable_values, operation_name, extra_args, upload_files)
    315             try:
--> 316                 result = await resp.json(content_type=None)
    317 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py in json(self, encoding, loads, content_type)
   1098         if self._body is None:
-> 1099             await self.read()
   1100 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py in read(self)
   1036             try:
-> 1037                 self._body = await self.content.read()
   1038                 for trace in self._traces:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py in read(self, n)
    374             while True:
--> 375                 block = await self.readany()
    376                 if not block:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py in readany(self)
    396         while not self._buffer and not self._eof:
--> 397             await self._wait("readany")
    398 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py in _wait(self, func_name)
    303                 with self._timer:
--> 304                     await waiter
    305             else:

CancelledError: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py in wait_for(fut, timeout, loop)
    491             try:
--> 492                 fut.result()
    493             except exceptions.CancelledError as exc:

CancelledError: 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/jj/c4zk0t9j2yq4ntqlxg67nznm0000gp/T/ipykernel_78199/1000501165.py in <module>
----> 1 rez = result.result()

/var/folders/jj/c4zk0t9j2yq4ntqlxg67nznm0000gp/T/ipykernel_78199/2766913208.py in main(transport, query)
     54     ) as session:
     55         gql_query = gql(query)
---> 56         result = await session.execute(gql_query)
     57         return result
     58 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gql/client.py in execute(self, document, variable_values, operation_name, serialize_variables, parse_result, get_execution_result, **kwargs)
   1218 
   1219         # Validate and execute on the transport
-> 1220         result = await self._execute(
   1221             document,
   1222             variable_values=variable_values,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gql/client.py in _execute(self, document, variable_values, operation_name, serialize_variables, parse_result, **kwargs)
   1124 
   1125         # Execute the query with the transport with a timeout
-> 1126         result = await asyncio.wait_for(
   1127             self.transport.execute(
   1128                 document,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py in wait_for(fut, timeout, loop)
    492                 fut.result()
    493             except exceptions.CancelledError as exc:
--> 494                 raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc
    495             else:
    496                 raise exceptions.TimeoutError()

TimeoutError:
```